# How prove this inequality $a^2m_{b}m_{c}+b^2m_{c}m_{a}+c^2m_{a}m_{b}\ge\frac{1}{4}(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2$

Tags: inequality, triangles, geometric-inequalities, sum-of-squares-method

If $a,b,$ and $c$ are the side lengths of a triangle, $m_a, m_b,$ and $m_c$ are the lengths of the medians, prove that

$$a^2m_{b}m_{c}+b^2m_{c}m_{a}+c^2m_{a}m_{b}\ge\dfrac{1}{4}(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2$$

$m_a^2 = \dfrac{2b^2+2c^2-a^2}{4}$

but I can't seem to arrive at the desired result.

Comment: By considering that $GA=\frac{2}{3}m_a$, this is an inequality about the circumradii of $GAB, GAC, GBC$. If we consider the perpendicular to the medians through the vertices and call $A'B'C'$ the triangle formed by them, $G$ is the Lemoine point of $A'B'C'$, since it is the centroid of its pedal triangle. The original inequality is so related with the distances of the Lemoine point from the vertices,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to prove that

$$\sum\limits_{cyc}m_a^2bc\geq\frac{4}{9}\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}m_a^2\right)^2$$ or 
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(2b^2+2c^2-a^2)bc\geq(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(-a^4+2a^3b+2a^3c-2a^2b^2-a^2bc)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(-2a^4+4a^3b+4a^3c-4a^2b^2-2a^2bc)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(-2a^4+a^3b+a^3c+2a^3b+2a^3c-4a^2b^2+a^3b+a^3c-2a^2bc)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2(-a^2-b^2-ab+2ab+ac+bc)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2(c^2-a^2-b^2+2ab-c^2+ac+bc-ab)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2(c+a-b)(c+b-a)+\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2(c-a)(b-c)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2(c+a-b)(c+b-a)+(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2(c+a-b)(c+b-a)\geq0$$
Done!

Comment: Nice,+1. but why need prove $\sum_{cyc}m^2_{a}bc$?,it's $\sum_{cyc}a^2m_{b}m_{c}\ge \sum_{cyc}m^2_{a}bc$? why,can you explain detail? Thanks

Comment: @function sug Let $AA_1$, $BB_1$ and $CC_1$ be medians of $\Delta ABC$, $M$ is a center of gravity and $B_1$ is middle point of $MD$. Thus, medians of $\Delta AMD$ are $\frac{a}{2}$, $\frac{b}{2}$ and $\frac{c}{2}$ and sides of $\Delta AMD$ are $\frac{2}{3}m_a$, $\frac{2}{3}m_b$ and $\frac{2}{3}m_c$.